# Cross model validation before save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So I have an application I'm developing that processes transactions that are comprised of one or more accounts. For example: a $100 Walmart purchase may have $40 come from the grocery account and $60 come from the household account.

The form is roughly:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Transaction.user_id');
echo $this->Form->input('Transaction.description');
echo $this->Form->input('Transaction.amount');
echo $this->Form->input('AccountTransaction.0.account_id');
echo $this->Form->input('AccountTransaction.0.amount');
.
.
.
```

Where there can be one or more Account Transactions involved. Also, AccountTransaction has a transaction_id field.

When the form is submitted, I want to:

1. check to make sure that the sum of all the Account Transaction amounts is equal to the Transaction amount,
2. Save the Transaction and get its id
3. Save the Account Transactions using the Transaction id

So I can easily do those things in the controller, but I'm wondering if there is a way to set up validation in the Transactions model to check that all of the account transactions add up before saving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that I can see all the data with $this->data anyway, so I added a custom a validation checking against everything submitted. I end up getting a customized validation message attached to the right element and it works great:

```
public function accountsBalance($check) {
    $check = (float) $check['amount'];
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($this->data['AccountTransaction'] as $account) {
        $sum += $account['amount'];
    }
    if ($sum==$check)
        return true;
    $diff = $check-$sum ;
    $message = sprintf("This doesn't match what you entered in your accounts. The total for the accounts is $%0.2f. You're too %s by $%0.2f",
        $sum, $diff > 0 ? "high": "low", abs($diff));
    $this->validator()->getField('amount')
        ->getRule('balance')->message = $message;
    return false;
}
```

Then for the rule I have:

```
    public $validate = array(
    'amount' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
        ),
        'balance' => array(
            'rule' => array('accountsBalance'),
            'message' => 'The total needs to match your account entries'
        )
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - use [custom validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules).

Step 2 - ignore - this is done automatically assuming your associations are correct

Step 3 - use [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: I like this and this is the path that I started down, but I wanted to utilize the validation messages, so that didn't work for me. I finally realized that I have full access to $this->data in the validation function, so I used that instead. I'll put some excerpts of what I did in another answer.